# ADO: Use an agent pool across multiple projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to use an agent pool across multiple projects within the same ADO organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

> In Azure Pipelines, pools are scoped to the entire organization; so
> you can share the agent machines across projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser

> You're a member of the infrastructure team and would like to set up a
> pool of agents for use in all projects. First make sure you're a
> member of a group in All agent pools with the Administrator role by
> navigating to agent pools page in your organization settings. Next
> create a New agent pool and select the option to Auto-provision
> corresponding agent pools in all projects while creating the pool.
> This setting ensures all projects have access to this agent pool.
> Finally install and configure agents to be part of that agent pool.